# css border-image gradient solution

Tags: css

I've had a search around but cannot find a solution to the way I wish to use it.

My gradient will be border-top/bottom with a white center with a reflected 0% opacity. Giving the effect that you see a lot like this.

`border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(49%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));`

But I cannot seem to get it to work, any ideas? I can't think of a way apart from adding manual images above and below the divs, which seems like a terrible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is this

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 0px;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    border-image-slice: 20;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

I have used only the unprefixed syntax; it will work as is in Chrome. You can use the shorthand notation, but I think that this way is more easy to understand how it works.

I have also set a background on body (if not, it's difficult to tell the difference between white and transparent) and shadow on the div so that you can see the real diemnsions.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/TgX3n/)